# What's the difference between C++ constructor `new T` and `new T()`?

Tags: c++, new-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do the parentheses after the type name make a difference with new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/620137/do-the-parentheses-after-the-type-name-make-a-difference-with-new)

I have C/C# background. I'm learning C++.

In C++, there're so many constructor forms. I'm confusing about them.
These are my understandings. Is this correct?

```
struct T {};

// #1
T* a = new T;  // Regular form. Just allocate memory.
// My understanding in C.
T* a = malloc(sizeof(T)); 

// #2
T* a = new T(); // #1 + Calling constructor.
// My understanding in C.
T* a = malloc(sizeof(T));
T_ctor_func(a);
```